# Can you pass console.log() as a javascript expression into a HTML element method?

Tags: javascript, html, console.log, htmlelements

I want to know if it's possible to console log strings from a html element's method?

For example in an html document with:

```
<body>
  <form action="#">
    <label for="name"></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" onblur={console.log("Foo")}>
  </form>
</body>
```

I was able to console log numbers but not strings or booleans. Is is possible?

Comment: Yes you can, just use onblur="console.log('Foo')", but it's not a good practice to log from html, do it calling a function from your js file instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course try this code.
The onblur attribute fires the javascript code at the moment that the element loses focus

```html
    <form action="#">
        <label for="name"></label>
        <input type="text" id="name" onblur="console.log('test')">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know console.log() needed to be in quotation marks.

Comment: You can use any other javascript code, but it is not best practice